# Angularjs Directive not working "Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So am using 1.20 rc2 and trying to implement a directive:

```
var directives = angular.module('directives', ['controllers']);

directives.directive("drink", function()
{
return 
{
    template: '<div>{{flavor}}</div>',
    link: function(scope){
        scope.flavor = "cherry";
    }
}
});
```

the directive gets called in the main JS file

```
 var comsumerApp = angular.module('comsumerApp', ['ngRoute','controllers', 'services', 'directives']);
```

All the controllers work as do the services but when trying to do this I get this error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

then I get the

> $injector:modulerr error.

Commenting out the "drink" directive stops this error so obviously it's something to do with the : or something.

Can anyone shine a light on this problem I'm totally lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try removing the linebreak before the opening bracket:

```
return 
{
    template: '<div>{{flavor}}</div>',
    link: function(scope){
        scope.flavor = "cherry";
    }
}
```

to this:

```
return {
    template: '<div>{{flavor}}</div>',
    link: function(scope){
        scope.flavor = "cherry";
    }
}
```

It might be due to `automatic semicolon insertion`, so your browser inserts an `;` after the `return`, because it thinks you just missed it..

Comment: This answer is correct, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons

I prefer to use 1TBS when working in Javascript, even if only to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, coming from c/c++ etc etc I was unaware whitespace affected it!